# How To Skip Message From SupreGroup or channel to Bot by c#?

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

i want to skip updates from supergroup or channel by c# 
used telegram-bot 11.3 .

```
  foreach (var update in updates)
    {

      offset = update.Id + 1;

      if (update.Message.Chat.Type.GetType().ToString() != "Supergroup" || update.Message.Chat.Type.ToString() != "Channel")
      //if (update.Message.Chat.Type.ToString() != Supergroup || update.Message.Chat.Type.ToString() != "Channel")
         {
```

Comment: what c# library are you using?

Comment: my library is telegram.bot

Comment: `foreach (var update in updates)
                {
                    if (update.Type == UpdateType.ChannelPost || update.Type == UpdateType.EditedChannelPost || update.Type == UpdateType.EditedMessage || update.Type == UpdateType.UnknownUpdate)
                    {
                        continue;
                    } else {...}}`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41519495/how-to-solve-disturbance-in-my-bot-in-c